# Can't replace HTML text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to use the code made available here to edit HTML files using Python:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-modify-html-using-beautifulsoup/

```
    # Python program to modify HTML
    # with the help of Beautiful Soup

    # Import the libraries
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    import os
    import re

    # Remove the last segment of the path
    base = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    # Open the HTML in which you want to make changes
    html = open(os.path.join(base, 'gfg.html'))

    # Parse HTML file in Beautiful Soup
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

    # Give location where text is
    # stored which you wish to alter
    old_text = soup.find("p", {"id": "para"})

    # Replace the already stored text with
    # the new text which you wish to assign
    new_text = old_text.find(text=re.compile(
        'Geeks For Geeks')).replace_with('Vinayak Rai')

    # Alter HTML file to see the changes done
    with open("gfg.html", "wb") as f_output:
        f_output.write(soup.prettify("utf-8"))
```

But nothing really happens, I tried changing the way the file is opened and changing the HTML file type, but it does nothing.

I'm not very practiced when it comes to programming so I don't know how well I will be able to answer any questions, but I will try my best to give any opportune information.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where are you using the variable `new_text` ?

Comment: next_text can be also omitted at all, ```.replace_with``` should affect whole the soup

Comment: html = open(os.path.join(base, 'gfg.html'), *'r'*) then html.close() at a certain point...maybe some conficlict with file descriptors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working fine when you have both the files right next to each other in a single directory:
[files in same directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFhjC.png)

- "Geeks for Geeks" present within a p tag with id "para".

  <p id="para">Geeks For Geeks</p>
- When you have other tags within enclosing p tag with id "para".

  <p id="para"><strong>Geeks For Geeks</strong></p>

If you are using a code editor (such as Atom or Sublime) you should be able to see the changes. In case of text editors, the changes may not reflect right away unless you manually reopen the file (ensuring you have not saved the file after running the Python script).

So my suggestion is:

1. Keep them both in the same directory.
2. Close the html file before running the Python script
3. After the script has been executed through cmd/bash (or built-in IDE console), reload the web page.

Feel free to reach out in case if the issue still persists.

Thanks.